# how to add parantheses in a table JOIN , Active Records Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

hi i am using codeigniter active records , i want to create a talbe join

this is my query

```
    $table = $this->mastables ['table1'];
    $table1 = $this->mastables ['table2'];

    $this->db->select ( 'a.RelationshipCategoryName,a.RelationshipCategoryID,COUNT( b.ShopRelationshipID ) AS count' );
    $this->db->from ( $table . " as a" );
    $this->db->join ( $table1 . " as b", "(( a.RelationshipCategoryID=b.RecieverRelationshipCategory AND b.3rdPartyID=" .$shop_id. " ) OR (  a.RelationshipCategoryID=b.SenderRelationshipCategory AND b.ShopID=" .$shop_id. " )) AND b.IsDelete!=1", 'left' );
    $this->db->where ( 'a.ShopID', $shop_id );

    $this->db->where ( 'a.IsActive', 1 );

    if ($limit != NULL) {
        $this->db->limit ( $limit, $offset );
    }
    if ($oderby != NULL && $oder != NULL) {
        $this->db->order_by ( $oderby, $oder );
    }

    $this->db->group_by ( 'a.RelationshipCategoryID' );

    $query = $this->db->get ();
    if ($query->num_rows () > 0) {
        return $query->result_array ();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }
```

the error is

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') OR ( a.RelationshipCategoryID=b.SenderRelationshipCategory AND b.ShopID=11 )) ' at line 3

SELECT `a`.`RelationshipCategoryName`, `a`.`RelationshipCategoryID`, COUNT( b.ShopRelationshipID ) AS count FROM (`mas_shop_relationship_category` as a) LEFT JOIN `mas_shop_relationship` as b ON `a`.`RelationshipCategoryID`=`b`.`RecieverRelationshipCategory` AND b.3rdPartyID=11 ) OR ( a.RelationshipCategoryID=b.SenderRelationshipCategory AND b.ShopID=11 )) AND b.IsDelete!=1 WHERE `a`.`ShopID` = '11' AND `a`.`IsActive` = 1 GROUP BY `a`.`RelationshipCategoryID` ORDER BY `a`.`RelationshipCategoryName` asc LIMIT 5

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\elephanti2\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

the error is coming from this line

```
    $this->db->join ( $table1 . " as b", "(( a.RelationshipCategoryID=b.RecieverRelationshipCategory AND b.3rdPartyID=" .$shop_id. " ) OR (  a.RelationshipCategoryID=b.SenderRelationshipCategory AND b.ShopID=" .$shop_id. " )) AND b.IsDelete!=1", 'left' );
```

how to add this part of code correctly in my code

```
(( a.RelationshipCategoryID=b.RecieverRelationshipCategory AND b.3rdPartyID=" .$shop_id. " ) OR (  a.RelationshipCategoryID=b.SenderRelationshipCategory AND b.ShopID=" .$shop_id. " ))
```

Comment: It seems when query generate 2 paranthesess being escaped from here `(( a.RelationshipCategoryID=b`. Check your query again. It shouldnt be happen

Comment: @safarov  , so what can i do in this situation

Comment: Always try to make core SQL query, before making CI query.
if it is running in phpMyAdmin then only make CI version of that query

Answer (score 0):

It seems when query generate 2 paranthesess being escaped from here `(( a.RelationshipCategoryID=b..` Check your query again. Also for `db->select()` you should pass as second parameter as `false` to make not escape special characters

```
$this->db->select ('select query', false);
```

BUt its better to use only `$this->db->query('whole sql query');` for complex queries